# write(cardnum, delay = 0.1) TypeError: nt.write() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python

```
from random import *
from keyboard import *
from pyautogui import *
from time import *
from os import *
from random import *
cardnum = input('Введите номер карты \n>>>')
date = input('Введите дату карты \n>>>')
cvv = input('Введите номер карты\n>>>')
name = input('Введите имя владельца карты \n>>>')
address = ['Kurtuluş Mh.','Kennedy Cd', 'Kocatepe Mh.','Cennet Mh.','Bostancı Mh.','Karakusunlar Mh 1545 Sk No 7 - Balgat','İnönü Cd Malatyapark Alışveriş Merkezi No:192','Bostancı Mh.',' Ortamahalle Mh.','  Siteler Mh.','Üsküdar Cd No:5 D:11','Beştepeler Mh. Yaşam Cd. No:5 Pk:06510 Yenimahalle/ankara','Fulya Mh.','Beştepeler Mh.','Arnavutköy Merkez Mh.','  Camikebir Mah.7 Eylül sok.No:09(Old town) 09400 Kuşadası',' Fikirtepe Mh.','Merkez Mh.','Ataköy 7-8-9-10 Mh.','Kapaklı Köyü Hoyran Mahallesi No:25','Tomtom Mh.','Emniyet Mh.','Çarşı Cd No:3','Akşemseddin Mh.','Kızlar Pınarı Mh.','Barbaros Blv','Büyük Dere Cd Yonca Apt. B Blok No:151 D:21', 'İstanbul İstiklal Caddesi Balo Sok.no 1/3']
cityes = ['Soma','Zeytinburnu','Bayrampaşa','Küçükçekmece','Kadıköy','Çankaya','Yeşilyurt','Fatih','Beyoğlu','Konak','Ümraniye','Aksu','Bayraklı','Çankaya','Muratpaşa','Fatih','Nilüfer','Kadıköy','Altındağ','Kartal','Kadıköy','Seyhan','Buca']
states = ['İstanbul','Antalya','Ankara','Malatya','Aydın',' Beşiktaş','Şişli','Beyoğlu','İzmir','Menderes','Bursa','Adana',]
postcode = ['45502','34025','34045','34290','34740','06530','44070','34098','34379','34435','35210','34775','07112','35495','35540','07160','34122','34720','01010','35380']
while True:
    ready = input(f'Как надо будет вывести нажмите Enter')
    sleep(3)
    moveTo,(800, 515)
    click()
    sleep(0.3)
    write(cardnum, delay = 0.1)
    sleep(0,3)
    moveTo,(741,626)
    click()
    write(date, delay = 0.1)
    sleep(0.3)
    moveTo(1020,605)
    click()
    write(cvv, delay = 0.1)
    sleep(0.3)
    moveTo(740,715)
    click()
    write(name, delay = 0.1)
    moveTo(1180,845)
    click()
    sleep(5)
```

the error message:
[image: the error message] i don't know that i should add, because if i will remove `delay` it will give me another error

[image: error, that i would receive if i would remove the delay] I really don't know that parametr i haven't written

Comment: This is one reason not to use `from ... import *`.

Comment: Please add the definition of `nt.write()`. If it's from another module, check its documentation. It has two required arguments, you're missing one of them.

Comment: `os.write` requires an explicit file descriptor as its first argument. Any reason  you are using that instead of `print`?

Comment: If you are expecting `write` to have been exported from *another* module, it probably was... until you redefined `write` by writing `from os import *`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the `write` function you think you are. When you wrote `from pyautogui import *`, the global name `write` was bound to `pyautogui.write`. But the `os` module *also* exports a `write` function, and `from os import *` redefined the name `write`.

```
>>> from pyautogui import *
>>> write
<function typewrite at 0x104c585e0>
>>> from os import *
>>> write
<built-in function write>
```

Don't use `from ... import *`; just import the module and use qualified names like

```
import pyautogui

...

pyautogui.write(...)
```

or import the names you expect to use expicitly.

```
from pyautogui import write

...

write(...)
```

That way, if you do write `from os import write`, it should be more obvious that you have introduced a name collision.